# Just created an Ubuntu VM on Google Cloud, but I cant sign into it

Tags: password, cloud, google

I created an Ubuntu Pro VM using Google Cloud and I'm connecting to it with Chrome Remote Desktop following Ubuntu's guide. Everything was working flawlessly and I got to the desktop page on my Ubuntu instance. However I tabbed out for a few minutes and when I came back I was locked for inactivity and I was being requested to enter a password. I never set a password and everything I've tried doesnt work. Here's an image of what I'm stuck at:

[image]

Is there anything I can enter on the command line to fix this maybe? I have no clue what to do.

Comment: What *have* you tried?  "everything i've tried" is a non-helpful statement because we can't read your mind, and don't know what you have or haven't tried yet.  (Worst case you just nuke the cloud VM and set it up again, then set a password BEFORE you tab away)

Comment: A link in your question to the guide you used would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no password if you haven't set a password when installing Ubuntu. Just click on the password entry field under your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to log in. After you log in you should create a stronger user password than no password to protect your Google Cloud Ubuntu VM.